# Rails 3 app works, integration test fails: how to fix cookie issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing

I have a simple Rails 3 app: no models, one view and one controller with a single `index` method which produces static content.  It works fine: when I manually browse to `'/'` I see my static content.

Then I added an integration test:

```
# myproj/test/integration/routes_test.rb
class RoutesTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest
  test 'default_route' do
    get '/'
    assert_response :success, @response.body
  end
end
```

When running this test via `rake`, it tells me that `GET '/'` is responding with 500.  Examination of the log output reveals this message in the response body:

```
A secret is required to generate an integrity hash for cookie session
data. Use config.secret_token = "some secret phrase of at least 30
characters" in config/initializers/secret_token.rb
```

Of course `secret_token.rb` exists and contains a properly formatted secret (it was generated by Rails 3 itself.)

Anyone out there know how to enable integration testing in Rails 3?  I'm guessing perhaps I need to set some other configuration options to tell my app to accept integration tests.

Comment: I've never had trouble with the kind of thing you're trying to do.  You shouldn't have to do anything special.  If you're using Test::Unit, are you requiring 'test_helper', and is 'test_helper.rb' requiring `File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)`?

Comment: @Steve Jorgensen, thanks for your suggestion.  `test_helper.rb` is indeed needed, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the Rails-generated file `test_helper.rb`.  This contains the magic necessary to allow integration testing.

In your test file(s), prepend the line:

```
require File.join( File.dirname( __FILE__ ), '../test_helper.rb' )
```

The path `'../test_helper.rb'` above should be relative to the test file that includes it.

FYI: The above is a Ruby idiom for including files by with relative paths (like `#include "../foo.h"` in C.)  If you're using Ruby 1.9.x, you can use a simpler form:

```
require_relative '../test_helper.rb'
```